# Is there a secured file sharing portal to share the documents with clients?

Tags: ftp, dropbox

I am working on a project for a Tax related assignment. Requirement is , Individuals / Clients will post their documents in a folder. Each folder should be accessible only by the assigned client. When a client needs to post additional documents, they can revisit the folder and post it back.

We will have to control the user access / user visibility access on the folder level.

Is there a secured file sharing portal to share the documents with clients?

Comment: Anything third party is doomed to have privacy and trust issues with the third party service, a fundamental downside of "the cloud". I would suggest something self-hosted.

Comment: It is for a team of 2 people. Hoping to get more clients. Self Hosting will be more tedious. Preferable is to have a third party software which we and the clients can login and update their documents. Each client account should be accessible limited to only their documents.